Non-parametric one-sample mean test for a bounded variable (based on Chebyshev's inequality?)
The problem
I have $x_1, \ldots , x_n$ i.i.d. draws from r.v. $X$ such that $0 \leq X \leq 1$, but I can't make any other assumptions about the distribution.
I want to test the null hypothesis that $E(X) = \mu$.
Notably, I'd like to handle the case where $P(x_1 = x_2 = \ldots = x_n)$ is non-negligible but there are low probability "extreme" observations that "rescue" the overall mean.
Attempted solutions
It appears, that Chebyshev's inequality, can be used to derive a general test for mean (see Saw et
al. 1984, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality#Finite_samples,  ), but that test has somewhat low power and makes no use of the boundedness of $X$ (and hence upper bound on variance etc.)
There are also randomized algorithms to determine mean within certain error (e.g. https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1016/j.matcom.2019.01.011), but those optimize the number of samples, I would like to instead optimize power given fixed number of samples.
It appears that some version of this test should be known (or even implemented somewhere) and  I feel like I might be missing a keyword to search for those results.
In practice, I've found just running a t-test to work quite well for most of the cases I care about, except the situations when $X$ has small finite support and I observe only a small number of samples and thus sometimes get all/almost all samples with identical values and thus the t-test's estimate of variance is bad.
The question A generalized randomized mean estimate based on the Chebyshev inequality looks somewhat related, but currently has no answer.
EDIT  (Example from comments): Say my $H_0$ is that $E(X) = 0.5$. I observe ten samples $x_1 = x_2 = \ldots  = x_{10} = 0.49$. I shouldn't reject, because the data are fully consistent with the true distribution being e.g. $P(X=0.49) = 19/20, P(X=0.69)=1/20$ and for this distribution $H_0$ holds.
But if I observe $x_1 = x_2 = \ldots = x_{10} =0.01$, I reject with high confidence, because the data imply $P(X \leq 0.01) \geq \frac{1}{2}$ and thus to satisfy $H_0$ I would need something like $P(X \geq 0.99) \geq \frac{1}{2}$, which the data contradict with $p \approx 2^{-10}$.
It is something like this type of reasoning I'd like to formalize. The bounded extension of Chebyshev's inequality seems like a starting point.
Note that to a t-test / sign permutation test / bootstrap test the two cases above look identical - they would reject the null with high confidence in both cases.
Also note that the discreteness of the distribution is mostly a distraction - the problem is almost identical if instead of point masses I consider narrow peaks in a continuous density function.

It sounds like a permutation test should work, even with your discrete distribution. Optimizing power is not likely to be possible without utilizing some kind of model in some way.

@Glen_b Wouldn't permutation fail the same way as a t-test when all observed values are identical?

If they're all identical in the data, then yes, it would also fail. I think there's literally nothing that you can do in that case for what I think you're trying to do. You certainly cannot find differences where there are none in the data! I took "$P(x_1=x_2=...=x_n)>0$ to mean you had discrete data, but yes, if that is in fact the situation in your sample then you are stuck for most nonparametric tests (and also for many parametric tests). A notable exception for nonparametric tests would be a one-sample test compared to an externally hypothesized value -- but this is no use to you.

@Glen_b This is where the bounds info comes in: say my H0 is E(X) = 0.5. I observe 0.49 ten times.  I shouldn't reject, because it is possible the true distribution is P(X=0.49) = 19/20, P(X=0.69)=1/20. But if I observe 0.01 ten times, I reject with p < 1/1024. However to bootstrap/t test those two cases look the same

Oh, then I did misunderstand; this seems to be the case that I said didn't apply in my last sentence above. Consider a permutation test on the "0.01 ten times" case" with sample mean as the test statistic; under the usual permutation test for the one sample case (which assumes exchangeability of signs  under H0, for which symmetry about its center would be sufficient), all allocations of signs to the set of ten "0.1" values would give a p-value of $2^{-9}$ for a two tailed test and should lead to rejection. ... ctd

ctd ... Of course you'd be free to say that the assumption of exchangeability is not always plausible, and certainly you're right that the bounds on the support will matter in some cases.

@Glen_b But the sign permutation will give the same p-value for "ten times 0.01" case as well as "ten times 0.49" case - because it assumes symmetry around the hypothesized mean. But I cannot assume that. Especially when the hypothesized mean is not in the middle of the support.

It will indeed give the same p value. That doesnt make it wrong, of course.  In effect, you've  simply said 'I won't assume that under the null', which I feel I addressed ... you're entirely within your rights there

Unsurprisingly, it turns out that this is a well studied topic.
Just some entry points into the prior literature:

A possibly oldest reference is Anderson 1969: Confidence limits for the expected value of an arbitrary bounded random variable with a continuous distribution function

Romano & Wolf 2000: Finite sample nonparametric inference and large sample efficiency prove that there is an asymptotic upper bound on efficiency of any test in this setting and construct an (IMHO somewhat clunky) test that meets this asymptotic bound.

A modern take is Schlag's thesis New Method for Constructing Exact Tests
without Making any Assumptions

Another modern take (also solving for confidence sequences, allowing multiple looks at the data and optional stopping): Waudby-Smith & Aaditya Ramdas 2022: Estimating means of bounded random variables by betting


The latter two tests also claim good finite sample efficiency (I have yet to test myself)
An important connection is also to the results of Bahadur & Savage 1956: The nonexistence of certain statistical procedures in nonparametric problems where they show that in the general case (unbounded distributions), no useful test for the mean can exist. However, one can build one-sided tests for non-negative variables (e.g. Wang & Zhao 2003: Nonparametric tests for the mean of a non-negative population)
Also a broader reminder that CrossValidated won't reliably do your literature search for you even with a bounty :-D

Thank you very much for coming back with all this information!

I think for this there are several well known concentration inequalities that can be applied. In particular Hoeffding, Azuma, and McDiarmid. Not that there's any real difference between the bounds one gets in this setting (where all the variables are bounded in the same way).

This is useful, but the bounds appear quite weak - in particular, I am unable to uncover a distribution for $X$ and choice of $n$ such that the resulting p values have anything close to uniform distribution under the null...

@MartinModrák - is there any additional information you can provide here? For example, would you be able to provide a bound on the variance? If so you may be able to get stronger results using other inequalities.

Not really, I just wonder if there is a case where the Hoeffding bound is tight? The paper (if I read correctly) claims it is the tightest exponential bound possible but that might be the case, even if the bound is actually very loose for all cases

Just to clarify,  Hoeffding seems to be ignoring some of the information I have: 1) that the variables are i.i.d. and 2) the relative position of $\mu$ between the bounds (and thus a possible asymmetry in possible discrepancies)

Searching the lit on "concentration inequalities" yields some tighter bounds. Notably Bentkus 2004 seems improve substantially over Hoeffding in my test cases. Still possibly some space to improve, but this line of inquire has been fruitful.

Let $\mathcal B$ be the ensemble of distributions of random variables bounded to $[0, 1]$.
We have $n$ variables $x_1 ... x_n$ IID from some distribution in $\mathcal B$. We want to test the null $E(X) = \mu$.
Intuitively, if most of the data is close to $1$, then we should reject small values of $\mu$, like you had in your example. For example, if $95\%$ of the data is higher than $0.93$, small values of $\mu$ should be rejected.
We will write a family of tests to encode this intuition. For any $t, \mu \in [0, 1]$ such that $t > \mu$, consider the random variable $Y_{t, \mu}$

$P(Y=t) = p$
$P(Y=0) = 1-p$

with $p = \mu / t$.
Among the distributions in $\mathcal B$ with mean $\mu$, this is the random variable which maximizes $P(Y \geq t)$.
Now, consider the count of $x_i$ above $t$. Under $Y_{t, \mu}$, this is a Binomial $(\mu / t, n)$ variable. It thus has an explicit quantile function (which is complex, of course) and we can also perform a Gaussian approximation in the large-$n$ limit.
Once we have the $q_\alpha$ quantile of the Binomial $(\mu / t, n)$, we can define the test:
$$
\text{Count}(x_i \geq t) \geq q_\alpha \rightarrow \text{ reject } E(X) = \mu
$$
which is a test at level $\alpha$ throughout $\mathcal B$.
The following statements are non-obvious and are left as an exercise to the reader:

$Y_{t, \mu}$ maximizes the probability $P(Y \geq t)$.
The test has level $\alpha$ throughout $\mathcal B$.


That looks sensible, but I don't really understand how to choose $t$... It seems that I need $t$ to be data-dependent, or the test will perform terribly in some cases, but choosing $t$ to optimize for rejection based on data will compromise the error rates... Or am I missing something?

Also, for some cases, the test basically never rejects - consider $P(X=0.5) = 0.5, P(X=0.75)=0.5$  Choose $\mu = \frac{1}{2}, t = 0.75, \alpha = 0.05$ (the choice of $t$ is thus the best possible). The probability of rejecting, actually decreases with sample size as you are testing if draws from $Bin(0.5, n)$ exceed quantiles of $Bin(\frac{2}{3}, n)$, which they rarely do. The problem seems to be that the test is assuming all the lower values to actually be $0$ while they are non-zero.

You are right, this test fails to have power in some cases, and you have found one. The crux is that 1. The test is paranoid about missing mass at 0 2. The test is very insensitive to details of the distribution since it only cares about a single summary. The path forward I see is to fit multiple quantiles, but I'm not sure how that would translate into a concrete test.

I have asked a question dealing with how to combine tests together: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/651316/recipes-for-combining-multiple-null-hypothesis-tests

After some investigations, I am not sure the test is salvageable as stated - even if I choose $t$ to maximize rejection rates, its power is not competitive with tests derived from concentration inequalities (see the other answer), which in turn are not competitive to some other approaches I am testing.

Yeah it's very possible that this test is just focusing on the wrong distributions inside the problem. Creating tests to target non-parametric problems is really not my area of expertise, sadly. But I really love this problem which you have brought so I'll think about it more. Are you writing this up into a paper? If so, please share it here once you publish to arxiv
