Recipes for combining multiple null-hypothesis tests
I have two questions about hypothesis testing:

Is there one or multiple generic recipes for combining tests together? Some procedure that would produce a new better test $T_\star$ from two tests $T_1$ and $T_2$.
When considering a parametric family of test $a \rightarrow T_a$, is there a recipe to produce a test that tunes the parameter $a$ to the data but keeps the right power?

Or is there no generic solution and everything should be performed in an ad-hoc manner?
Context of the question
The context for this question is my answer here. The context is of finding a test for the mean of a bounded variable and I give a family of strict tests.
However, as noted by the OP, my family can be quite underpowered in simple cases due to it being very myopic due to it looking at a single summary of the data.
As a fix, I think it is natural to image combinations of tests, so that the blindspots of one test might be covered by another test. For example, we could:

try to combine multiple such tests together;
combine one such test with a standard student test for the mean;
tune the threshold parameter $t$ of my test family to the data.

These thoughts brought me to my question. In this case or in general, is there a recipe to do such combinations? Or must everything be done manually to show that a specific combination of tests has appropriate level but increased power?
My initial unsuccesful thoughts
Here are some ideas which I don't think work:

Brute-force combination based on bonferoni-style corrections for multiple testing

this is extremely pessimistic. If the tests are indeed complimentary, then their worst case scenarios should have no overlap. A bonferoni correction is going to be extremely underpowered and the real-level will be much below the nominal level
the more combinations we do, the more we will destroy the power of the combined test
(NB: recall that the rejection rate is typically continuous; the power at almost-null models is thus equal to the level)


Naive combination with no correction: the null is rejected if any test rejects.

this is the opposite extreme, assuming that all tests are somehow perfectly aligned
the combined test will reject the null too much



Overall, both of these approaches seem way to coarse to achieve much.
